# Sort predetermined fields with a macro

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I would like to sort my table depending on five parameters.
I have the following columns:

- Name TX
- Name RX
- Data
- Zeitraster
- Richtung
- Botschaftzahl
- LSB Position
- große
- Coef
- Min
- Max

Sorted in this order:

1. Data
2. Zeitraster
3. Botschaftzahl
4. Richtung
5. LSB Position

Comment: Where are you getting the parameters from?

Comment: Is the primary key *Data* or *LSB Position*? Is your list of fields from primary to secondary, etc or vise-versa? Ascending or Descending for each foeld?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA will only allow three *keys* to sort on in any one process. If more than three keys are required, you sort the last keys first and then return to the three most primary keys.

```
Sub custom_sort()
    Dim vKEYs As Variant
    vKEYs = Array("Data", "Zeitraster", "Botschaftzahl", "Richtung", "LSB Position")
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(Application.Match(vKEYs(3), .Rows(1), 0)), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Key2:=.Columns(Application.Match(vKEYs(4), .Rows(1), 0)), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(Application.Match(vKEYs(0), .Rows(1), 0)), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Key2:=.Columns(Application.Match(vKEYs(1), .Rows(1), 0)), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Key3:=.Columns(Application.Match(vKEYs(2), .Rows(1), 0)), Order3:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes

        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

That uses the data block starting in A1. It uses the `application.Match` across the header row to get the position of each sort key column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data=>Sort which will bring up a dialog box to allow you to do that.
In VBA you can invoke the Sort function.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort....
```

Easiest way to do this would actually be to record it and all should become clear.